# Wso2 connection with Mysql (SSL connection) in azure

Tags: mysql, wso2

Not able to change the default H2 database to Mysql in WSO2 . 
Getting SSL handshake error when connecting from WSO2 to Mysql(MySql is a saas hosted in azure)

Steps I have taken to connect to the MySQL 5.7 from wso2 api manager 260

1) I have added the https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem to the client-truststore.jks

Link form where I got the crt is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl

2) I have updated the master-datasources.xml file

```
<url>jdbc:mysql://***.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/regdb?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=false</url>
<username>***</username>
<password>***</password>
<driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
```

3) Created the schema and the required tables as well

Below is the error log when starting the wso2 server

```
Start Level Event Dispatcher, received EOFException: error
Start Level Event Dispatcher, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Start Level Event Dispatcher, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Start Level Event Dispatcher, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Start Level Event Dispatcher, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

Comment: the master-datasources.xml is updated as               <url>jdbc:mysql://***.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/regdb?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=false</url>
    <username>***</username>
    <password>***</password>
    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>

Comment: is everything working fine without SSL?